# Can Wireshark decode Hessian-data?

Tags: java, wireshark

We are debugging a problem with our application using `tcpdump`-captured data in Wireshark.

Some of the data is in binary format ([Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-serialization.html)):

```
Content-Type: x-application/hessian
```

which is a pain to decode by hand. I wonder, if Wireshark has an option/plugin, that would decode and show it automatically... Does it?

P.S. Wish, there was a `hessian`-tag already...

Comment: Given that searching for "wireshark hessian" doesn't return anything useful the answer is probably no ...

Comment: Of course, I searched for it myself before asking. Yet, this seems like such an obvious feature to add, I thought, maybe, they've already done it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sadly, the answer is "No". There is [hope](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12551), but the feature is not implemented at the time of this typing.